# Why is grouping $2n$ students into pairs NOT equal to $^{2n}C_2$?

Tags: combinatorics

I just don't understand.

The way to couple $2n$ people into pairs $\dfrac{2n!}{(n!(2!))^n}$

I get this reasoning. $2n!$ is the rearrangement of the $2n$ students, divide it $n!$ and $2!$ to get rid of repeated groupings.

Shouldn't $^{2n}C_2$ give me the same number of groupings though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should it?  $\binom{2n}{2}$ simply counts the number of ways to select $2$ people out of a group of $2n$ people.  It doesn't say anything about how the other $2n-2$ people not selected are arranged.

Answer (score 1):

${2n\choose 2}$ is the number of wais of selecting **a single pair** of people out of a group of $2n$ people.